# How Java Thread Pool works?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am working on an IoT project where devices send data to our Java Application called Gateway Adapter (GA).
In java I am using Thread Pool to start a new thread for every message we received from devices.

I have following code for Thread Allocator and Runnable Thread.

```
public class ThreadAllocator {

  /** The thread pool. */
  private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(1000);

  public void allocateThread(IoSession session, String message) {
    LOGGER.info("Entering allocateThread");
    executorService.execute(new HelperThread(null,session, message));       
  }
}
public class HelperThread implements Runnable {

  private String message;

  public HelperThread(String message) {
    LOGGER.info("Entering HelperThread");
    this.message = message;
  }

  public void run() {
    LOGGER.info("Entering run");
    // Process Message
  }
}
```

With above code when i did a load testing by sending around 5000 messages, I could see messages "Entering allocateThread" and "Entering HelperThread" 5000 times in log file but my run method executed only 1000 times means message "Entering run" was there in log file only 1000 times. Due to which other 4000 messages could not processed.

Is it the expected behavior "newWorkStealingPool" Thread Pool? Will it only execute tasks equals to number provided in its constructor? E.g. Executors.newWorkStealingPool(**1000**);

Kindly suggest the solution?
Am i missing some configuration or it is not the correct Thread Pool for my scenario? Then which Thread Pool will work correctly in this case?

Really appreciate your help.

Regards,
Krishan

Comment: The parameter to newWorkStealingPool() is meant to be more something like the number of processors available to execute threads, not the number of tasks to (eventually) execute...  So you should just not pass anything it, and let it default to the number of actual processors.  However, I don't know why it stops at 1000...

Comment: Is your Logger thread safe ??

Comment: @Mukesh, Not sure. I am using slf4j Logger. In log4j.properties I have following:
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FILE, CONSOLE

log4j.logger.io.netty=FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache=FATAL
log4j.logger.net.sf=FATAL

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log.txt
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=1000MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10

Comment: Your HelperThread Constructor accepts one argument how come you are passing three arguments while passing it to executor ?? Plus as the argument to newWorkStealingPool(1000) here 1000 is parallelism and not number of threads which is calculated based on  parallelism you pass as argument. Try not to pass anything to the newWorkStealingPool() and try.